# Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that for all $x\in(0,\infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that for all $x\in(0,\infty)$, it holds that $f(2x)=f(x)$. Show that the function defined by the equation $$g(x)=\int_x^{2x}\frac{f(t)}{t}dt$$ for $x>0$ is a constant function.

My approach: It is given that $f$ is continuous $\forall x>0$. Thus from the definition of $g$ we can conclude by the Leibniz Rule, that $g$ is differentiable for all $x>0$ and $$g'(x)=\frac{f(2x)}{x}-\frac{f(x)}{x}.$$ Now since $f(2x)=f(x)$ holds true $\forall x>0,$ we can conclude that $g'(x)=0,$ $\forall x>0$.

Now let us choose an infinitesimal real number $\epsilon>0$ and assume that $f(0+\epsilon)=f(\epsilon)=L$. Also let $x_1>\epsilon$ be arbitrary. Now since $g$ is differentiable for all $x>0$, implies that $g$ is differentiable on the closed interval $[\epsilon,x_1]$, which in turn implies that $g$ is continuous on the closed interval $[\epsilon,x_1]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(\epsilon,x_1)$ with $g'(x)=0$ for all $x\in(\epsilon,x_1)$. Thus we can conclude that $g$ is constant, that is, $g(x)=c,$ for all $x\in[\epsilon,x_1]$, where $c$ is some constant. Actually by MVT, we can show that $c=L$.

Now since $x_1$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that $g$ is a constant function in its domain.

Is the approach correct and rigorous enough?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} g(x)=0$ $\forall x>0 \implies g(x)$ is constant, why is the last paragraph needed?

Comment: @Learnmore, as per my knowledge if a function $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$ with $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, then we can conclude that $f$ is constant in $[a,b]$. But, here the problem is that $(0,\infty)$ is an open interval.

Comment: Let $x_1 < x_2$ be any positive numbers. By the Lagrange mean value theorem $g(x_2 ) - g(x_1 ) = (x_2  - x_1 )g'(x^ *  ) = 0$ with some $x^\ast$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$. Hence, $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$ for any $0<x_1 < x_2$ meaning that $g$ is a constant function.

Comment: You don't need closed intervals for the result: If $f$ is differentiable on an interval $I$ and derivative $f'$ vanishes on $I $ then $f$ is constant on $I$.